# Is it possible to show heap memory size in Intellij IDE (Android Studio)?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I am searching for a way to display Heap Memory/force garbage collection.

I have already tried to search through settings, however all I could gather was about setting JVM parameters in Android Studio config.

Does Android Studio have such functionality?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's exist but not visible by default.
go to Setting > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > In Window Option Segment > tick "Show memory indicator" and save setting.

[image]

After that you can view memory indicator in bottom right corner, you can trigger garbage collector by click on memory bar.

Comment: Or press "double shift" and search for memory indicator.

Comment: FYI as of 2020.1.4 webstorm, the option does not exist in menu anymore. Double shift works though

Comment: Doesn't exist for Intellij 2020.2 either. This works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46668686/1788806 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62385463/1788806

Answer (score 104):

In the `IntelliJ version 2020.1` windows & macOS

1. Right-click about the bottom right.

[image]

2. Selected `"Memory Indicator"`

[image]

3. Show already.

[image]

Work for me.

Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html#enable-memory-indicator

Comment: in Linux is exactly the same, thanks!, IDK why is removed from settings menu

Comment: for some reason, this also works without having to restart IntelliJ :D

Comment: Its worth noting that this is the IDE memory, not the running application's memory

Answer (score 97):

1. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> two times.
2. Search for "memoryIndicator" in the search box.
3. Toggle on the memory indicator option.
4. (You might need to restart IntelliJ for changes to take effect.)

Comment: It's `Ctrl + shift + A` on linux with Gnome key mapping